# Spotfire - How to have a property control on unique not-filtered values from a column of a datatable

Tags: datatable, properties, controls, spotfire, tibco

I have a dropdown list (that is used to filter a table).

At the moment I have this dropdown list with unique values from a column of a datatable. I can't figure out how to only have not filtered values.

---

Little example :

```
// Table from which unique not-filtered values should be get
Column
-------
   A
   B
   C
```

Let's say I use a filter to only have A and B. My dropdown list should only propose values A and B. At the moment I have A, B and C.

I can't find a way to do this, someone has an idea?

Answer (score 3):

It's not an ideal solution, but one option is as follows:

Add a data table that *only* has the column you want in your dropdownlist.
Change the settings to turn this new data set into a Data on Demand --
Hit the "Define Input" button, select "Values from column", select your first data table, and select the matching column.  Then limit by the filtering scheme you want to be applied (make sure to deselect the marked rows default).
Make sure to check "Load automatically" in the data table's On-Demand settings.

This new data table now only has the filtered values, so you can use this as the source for your DropDownList.

Cons: It has to reload every time you select things in your filter.  Depending on how long it takes to pull the values, this may become obnoxious.